# Car and Paint Class Relationship

Tags: oop, object, inheritance

Interview question:

1) There is a "Paint" class and a "Car" class, with several subclasses like Red, Blue etc colors. Explain how do you separate Colors from Car class? and how is it important?

2) Using an object oriented approach, if you have a class "Car", how would "Paint" class relate to "Car"?

Both are pretty much same questions, just wanna know different perspectives-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Car "has" Paints, I'd guess the interviewer wants you to explain `Inheritance` and `Composition`. Example, Red, Blue inherit from Paint since they have "is a" relationship, while Car has paints and it is example of composition. Then some common follow-up questions would be when to use composition over inheritance, is it better to use composition over inheritance, if so why, etc.

Comment: Isnt it supposed to be aggregation instead of composition - In aggregation, the color of the car can change unlike composition?